# Pulling Facebook friends from app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using the Facebook API to login to a website, can you pull a list of that user's friends who have logged in using the same app id?

Comment: Not an expert with Facebook API but I quess if a user is using the same app, he/she has most likely accepted to share his/her profile and login info with the app, so the answer for short is YES.

Comment: You can record each user who logs into the app and then get the user's friends and see which of them have used the app before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's a Graph API method for this yet, there's a REST method though called [`friends.getAppUsers`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getAppUsers/).

Now to do this without REST API there are a couple of ways, one of them:

1. User login using Facebook => insert a new record in your `user` table if not exists
2. Retrieve the user's friends by calling the `/USER_ID/friends` connection
3. Prepare a comma separated string of the user friends' ids to get the users (friends) from your `user` table: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_fb_id IN ($friends_id)`

Answer (score 0):

U can look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.get/
List the friends and show in your app if they are connected. But when it is not your app. I think you can't do it.